# Passing QueryString into another Entity Framework page

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, web-applications, webforms

I have a web form (Page1.aspx) in which I am passing an ID as query string to another page (Page2.aspx). 
Now in this page I have EntityDataSource which binds to GridView. How should I populate this gridview with that ID?

Eg. If my ID is 1056, then in my DataGridView in Page2.aspx should populate elements of this ID.

This is the code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string getEntity = Request.QueryString["EntityID"];
        int getIntEntity = Int32.Parse(getEntity);

        if (getIntEntity != 0)
        {
            //What should I do here???
        }

    }
```

What should I do? Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See "Using a Control Parameter to Set the "Where" Property" in this tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-–-getting-started-part-3

The process will be similar except as "Parameter source" select QueryString instead of Control.

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I did that. But I am getting this error: A property with name 'EntityID' does not exist in metadata for entity type 'EntityRegistration.FrontEnd.Entity'.

Answer (score 1):

1.Take id from query string:

```
var strId = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["ID"];
int id = 0;
int.TryParse(strId, out id);
if(id != 0)
{
  ...
}
```

2.Pass id to DataSource(mb [this](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/entitydatasource-using-parameters.html) article help you) in Page_load event.

Comment: I got it. However, this does not answer my ques. If I am not mistaken I have captured that ID from previous page. Now if that ID is not NULL then what should I do?

Comment: @klm: If id not null you should pass it to datasource as parameter. Something like *entityDataSource.Parameters.Add("id" .. );*